# ParseInt of non numeric value does not equal NaN?

Tags: javascript, nan

I am trying to implement some javascript in my website but have gotten a problem when checking if a user input is a number. For example when passing `"r"` into `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` the result in the console is `NaN` as expected. But when comparing `NaN` and `ParseInt("r")` the result is false (they are not the same) when I would've expected the comparison to return true

*code and console output*

```
console.log(parseInt("r"), parseInt("r") === NaN)
```

> NaN false

```
console.log(parseFloat("r"), parseFloat("r") === NaN)
```

> NaN false

Comment: use `isNaN` function

Comment: NaN equals nothing. Not even itself. `NaN === NaN` is false **by definition**.

Comment: `Object.is(parseFloat("r"), NaN)`